# Corroded iPhone Lightning connector

Tags: cleaning, technology

How do I fix the lightning connector (not the cable) of my iPhone which I believe is either corroded or covered with carbon?

Comment: Hi user34793, Welcome to Lifehacks. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience. You may want to visit the [Tour] and [Help] to find out more about our quirky site. You'll get a start on your accumulation of 'rep' (reputation) points for your effort.

Comment: You mention that the 'connector' is corroded. Do you mean the contacts inside the iPhone Lightning cable receptacle or the plug that goes inside the receptacle? Either way, cleaning Lightning connector contacts are also discussed in a similar question which may also be of some help: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/11738/removing-corrosion-on-the-contacts-of-an-apple-usb-to-lightning-cable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Spray the connector with electrical contact cleaner.
2. Find a very small brush (something like an interdental brush) and gently scrub the connector.
3. Spray the connector again with electrical contact cleaner, to flush out any loose debris.

Answer (score 0):

If it’s actually corroded away there’s little you can do about it.

On the other hand, if it’s merely dirt, grease or grime, use a pencil eraser.

Comment: not true, electrical contract cleaner will remove a lot of _surface_ corrosion

Comment: @bigbadmouse - sure it will, but that's not what I said. I said "if it's corroded away". People seem to have a remarkable propensity for scorching the contacts off lightning connectors. No metal left, nothing to clean.